# Literal translation of the word シレジレ

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm not sure how to translate the word シレジレ.

Does it mean something like "perky, confident, opinionated, presumptuous"?

If so, may シレジレメカコラム be translated as "All-knowing Mecha Column" or "Wise Guy's Mecha Column"?

Comment: Japanese-speaker here.  I know what ツレヅレ means but have no idea what シレジレ would mean.

Comment: and what it means?)

Comment: You could try [looking things up in a dictionary.](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%84%E3%83%AC%E3%83%85%E3%83%AC)

Comment: 「ツレヅレ=tedious」としてしまうと、「つまらない/退屈なコラム」みたいになってしまいそうですけど、大丈夫ですかね・・・？　「[徒然]{つれづれ}なるままに」か「[徒然草]{つれづれぐさ}」のニュアンスを調べた方がいいんじゃないかと思います・・・。「徒然草」では「つまらない作品」・「退屈なエッセイ」って意味で「徒然」を使っていないので。例えば　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q127740032

Comment: Looks like i used dictionary incorrectly.
Actually, i thought it was 「痴れ痴れ」 by kanji.
はい、分かりました。ありがとう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entry for 痴れ痴れ on Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C): 「いかにもとぼけたさま」 == "*looking extremely stupid [possibly intentionally]*".  I don't think you want that one either.  とぼける can mean *to play the fool*, i.e. to play dumb while actually being smart, or *to dissemble, to feign ignorance*, such as when asked about something, but it can also mean *to be vacant, absentminded* and *to go senile, as with old age*.

The シレ in 痴{し}れ痴{じ}れ is from verb 痴{し}れる, which (confusingly) kinda means the opposite of 知{し}れる.  Main definition for 痴れる in my copy of Shogakukan:

- 「判断{はんだん}・識別{しきべつ}の能力{のうりょく}が働{はたら}かなくなる。ぼける。ばかになる。」
  *To lose one's ability to make judgments or distinguish.  To become senile or dotty.  To become stupid or foolish.*

As suggested by 非回答者's ignorance of the term, it's probably not used very commonly in mainstream Japanese.  The katakana spelling only gets [162 Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%AC), actually collapsing to [just 38 hits if you click **Next** a few times](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%AC#q=%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%AC&start=30).  The kanji spelling gets [677 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%22), collapsing to [just 109 hits if you click **Next** enough](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%22#q=%22%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%E7%97%B4%E3%82%8C%22&start=99), of which the first page is all dictionary sites, and a number of the hits on the next two pages are of sites explaining the term.

If you're trying to come up with a column title, this might not be the word to use.  If instead シレジレメカコラム is something you found and you're wondering what it means, my rough guess would be "goofy mecha column", with an emphasis on the "ditzy" shades of meaning in "goofy" (some of the Google image results for just 痴れ suggest "ditzy" in feminine ways; various images are NSFW, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader).  Without more context, though, that's just a shot-in-the-dark guess.

Comment: 「ツレヅレメカコラム　螺子の囁き」っていうタイトルの作品があるみたいです。http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rasenjin/comment?date=20070918&section=p2

Comment: やっぱ、だからこそ「シレジレメカコラム」が[見つからなかった](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%AC%E3%83%A1%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%22)のでしょうね。ありが‌​とうございます。

Comment: Huh.  Is there any particular reason someone just downvoted this answer?  Downvoting without at least commenting isn't terribly constructive.